# Can a right-chiral electron annihilate on contact with a right-chiral positron?

Tags: particle-physics, antimatter, chirality

Or, do two particles have to be 'anti' in every sense of the word?  (Opposite charge, opposite chirality, etc.)

Edit: Just to clarify... Antiparticles can have multiple properties that are 'anti' of each other... An antiparticle can even be considered going backwards in time...

BUT, do two particles only have to have opposite electromagnetic charge (and equal mass) to annihilate upon contact???

Comment: Chirality is a property of fields, not particles.  Your question, strictly speaking is not correct.  Possible suggestion: longitudinal polarization.

Answer (score 2):

An electron and a positron can annihilate regardless of their spin states. However, their likelihood of annihilation depends on those spin states.

Answer (score 1):

Let's first clarify that your chirality definition is: the antiparticle of a right-chiral electron is left-chiral positron. Right? (Just make sure, since there are alternative definitions.)

If so, a right-chiral electron can not annihilate on contact with a right-chiral positron. The reason is that annihilation is accompanied with emitting a photon and QED is non chiral, which means pair-created/annihilated particles should be chirality neutral in aggregation.

That said, as @G.Smith pointed out, spin states can be flipped, since photons carry spin $\pm 1$.

More specifically, the electromagnetic gauge field $A_\mu$ comes with $\gamma^\mu$ when minimally coupled with electrons/positrons, as
$$
i\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu(\partial_\mu -eA_\mu i)\psi.
$$
And $\gamma^\mu$ is surely capable of changing the spin state without changing the chirality, given that $\gamma^0\gamma^\mu$ commutes with chirality projector $(1\pm\gamma^5)/2$, where $\gamma^0$ stems from Dirac conjugation $\bar{\psi} = \psi^\dagger\gamma^0$.